# file name displayed same for all fields, using codeigniter's upload library

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-uploading

I have a view file, which includes form:

```
form_upload('media_image_00');
form_upload('media_image_01');
.....
form_upload('media_image_14');
```

And my controller(I have set the validation rules in model):

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
    $config['upload_path'] = './my_image/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
    $config['max_size']         = '10240';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            for($i = 0;$i<=14;$i++){
            $name = 'media_image_0'.$i;
            if($i>9){
                $name = 'media_image_'.$i;
            } // end of if($i>9
            if(!empty($_FILES[$name])){
                $this->upload->do_upload($name);
                $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
                $_POST[$name] = $upload_data['file_name'];
                dump($upload_data['file_name']);
            }else{
                // do nothing
            }// end of if(!empty
        } // end of for loop
```

I want the dump($upload_data['file_name']) to dump the filename, only where the datas are selected & uploaded. Not in every field.
The problem is when I upload data only on media_image_00 & media_image_01, it automatically dumps the name of media_image_01 to every other field after it. File is not uploaded again but the name is same for every field after media_image_01.

I don't know what the problem is. May be it is something to do with array in codeigniter.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Instead of `!empty($_FILES[$name])` try using `isset($_FILES[$name])`, or even `$_FILES[$name]['size'] > 0`

Comment: Solved it,
I replaced third if condition with this:

Comment: if(!empty($_FILES[$name])){
         $this->upload->do_upload($name);
         $_POST[$name] = ($_FILES[$name]['name']);
        dump($_POST[$name]);
     }else{
     } // Do nothing